# How can I view the content of cookies in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I can only [browse them and delete them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHo0m.jpg).
What I found online doesn't apply to my situation because my user interface is different. I'm using version 100.0.4896.75 on Ubuntu 20.04.
I know that I can use the chrome devTools as a workaround but I would like to do it the other way, without having to visit each website.

Comment: you will need one or more chrome extensions to do what you want. there are a bunch out there, so you'll have to find the ones you like.

Comment: @FrankThomas This is so weird. I could swear I used to be able to *view* cookies right in the Chrome settings!

Comment: Usually we can view the cookies data in `chrome://settings/siteData` but now it seems that Google deprecated them in Chrome 108? I can't find anything other than [this 2021 Ghacks' article](https://www.ghacks.net/2021/09/04/google-plans-to-replace-chromes-cookies-and-site-data-controls-with-an-inferior-option/).

Answer (score 11):

You can visit the website you're trying to get the cookies from, then open the devtools.

Next, in the top bar, click on the "double-arrow (>>)"-icon in the band at the top of the devtools, then select "Application".

From here, you should see a "Storage" section in the right, in which you can find the "Cookies"-menu. Here you can find key-value pairs for all cookies currently accessed by the site.

Answer (score 7):

It was possible to see all cookies content for all domains in the settings with Chrome version 107.0.5304.107. I updated to 108.0.5359.72 and now it's only possible to delete data or set domain rights...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159482)

Answer (score 0):

Click the icon on the left side of the Omnibox and select Cookies. A dialog will appear. Navigate the tree until you find a cookie you want to see, then select it. You'll see as much of the cookie as will fit in your box.